# How to correctly initialize large sized PDA accounts with zero copy?

Tags: anchor, pda

I have the following example: ZStruct is a PDA of IdentifierKey:

```
pub const array_size = 10_000;

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]
pub struct ZStruct {
  pub identifier_key: Pubkey // 32
  pub arr: [u128; array_size] // 16 * 10_000 = 160_000
}
```

The initialization ix for this PDA:

```
pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
          
  Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {
 
 // ... accounts

 #[account(zero)]
  pub zstruct: AccountLoader<'info, ZStruct>
}
```

A simple test:

```
const identifier_key = web3.Keypair.generate();
 
const pda_addr = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([ identifier_key.toBuffer() ], programId);
 
await program.methods.initialize()
  .accounts({
    zstruct: pda_addr
  })
  .preInstructions([
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
          fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
          newAccountPubkey: pda_addr,
          lamports: await provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(160_040),
          space: 160_040,
          programId: program.programId
        })
    ])
  .rpc();
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Signature verification failed.

I think this is probably because it's not possible for anyone to initialize a PDA using a SystemInstruction. This would've worked in case zstruct were a regular account and not PDA(by adding the account keypair as signer on the test code).

I am looking for help with how to do this for PDAs and how to solve the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, PDA accounts are limited to an additional 10KB of account space on every invocation. The general process is to keep calling an instruction which calls `realloc` somewhere, extending the account by 10KB on each invocation.

The general procedure goes:

```
account_info.realloc(new_length, /* zero_init */ false);
```

I'm just not sure if Anchor supports reallocation yet!

Comment: You're correct. Since only the program itself can create PDAs, the only way to do this is to initialize a PDA with an initial account size and keep increasing memory via `realloc`.

And yes realloc is supported with Anchor: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/1943

Thanks for the answer!